# cells matching but some of the cells have space

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have the following issue.

[image]

1 - I'm trying to see if there are matchings between the cells in column B and the cells in column A

2 - If there is a matching, we copy the cells of column B into the first cell of column C.

One example : `1001Pharmacies` in `B7` has a match in either in `A5:A7`. Therefore I'm copying it in `C2`.

Adding to that, one of my other issue is that some of my cells have space between them like the one in `B9` and therefore cannot do a proper matching with cells in `A11:A13`.

If you have any insight, I would be glad.

**update**: I've tried that as a starting point

```
Function andyLookup(strInput As String, rngTable As Range, defaultvalue As String) As String
    Dim strArray() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strOut As String
    Dim temp1 As Variant

    strArray = Split(strInput, " ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(strArray)

        temp1 = Application.VLookup(strArray(i), rngTable, 2, 0)
        'if not found, apply default value
        If IsError(temp1) Then
        strOut = strOut & defaultvalue & " "
        Else
        strOut = strOut & temp1 & " "
        End If

    Next

    'remove trailing comma
    strOut = Left(strOut, Len(strOut) - 1)
    andyLookup = strOut

End Function
```

Comment: Can't spaces in B9 just replaced. Like ' ' replace with '' and then go for lookup.

Comment: This is purely a comment/question.  How much thought have you given to normalization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",""),A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```

Or if you specifically want to use VBA

```
Function andyLookup(strInput As String, rngTable As Range, defaultvalue As String) As String

Dim temp1 As Variant

     temp1 = Application.VLookup(Replace(strInput," ",""), rngTable, 2, 0)

     andLookup = IIf(IsError(temp1), defaultvalue, temp1)

End Function
```